# Custom web service in Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices

I would like to create a custom web service in my Salesforce organization to share some data when external application sends a request. The external application sends the request with some identifier. I need to respond with the related status.

Identifier can have 1 status(one-to-one mapping)
Identifier can have multiple children (one-to-many mapping)
How can I send this back to external application?

In 2nd case, I need to send both child I'd and statuses (map)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider generating a JSON response or XML response depending on what your external application is capable of consuming.

I would personally prefer to use JSON as I have done this before and works well.

Your response should look like this:

```
{"Response":[
    {"ID":"ABC", "Status":"New"},
    {"ID":"XYZ", "Status":"Completed"},
    {"ID":"PQR", "Status":"In-Progress"}
]}
```

Once you get the ID and Status map in a List , you can generate the JSON response using the Salesforce JSON Generator. Please find the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm)